# What would a minimum latex template must contain in order to successfully convert markdown to pdf?

Tags: pandoc

`pandoc -D latex` contains a lot of things, most of what I don't need. I am trying to clean it up to a minimum to make it easier to edit.

I thought this would be the most minimum to get started with:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$body$

\end{document}
```

I compiled with it like so: `pandoc *.md --template=the.template -o out.pdf` and received the following error:

```
Error producing PDF.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.5 \hypertarget
```

How may I fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\hypertarget` is defined by `hyperref` so you would need

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple template might be helpful :

https://gist.github.com/michaelt/1017790